# Json Data Forloop Issue

Tags: php, jquery

I am usig a for loop in order to process data, but it is not displaying properly. I'm really stuck on it. The data is coming from another script, but the issue is within the for loop. What am I missing?

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "more.php",
    data:"&max_id="+maxid, //Forms name
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        //var image = data.images;
        for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
            var image = data.images;
            var likes = data[i].likes[i];
            var comments = data[i].comments[i];
            var nextid=data[i].next_id;
            $(".row").append("<div class='col-md-2 col-sm-3'><div class='thumbnail'><img src='"+image+"' style='width: 100%;' alt='Gallery Image'><p><br/> Likes:"+likes+"  <br/> Comments: "+comments+" </p></div></div>");
        }
    }
});
```

My JSON data:

```
{
    "next_id":"1075182757212925396_588379938",
    "images":[
        "xyz.com",
        "abc.com",
        "def.com"
    ],
    "likes":[
        26,
        21,
        29
    ],
    "comments":[
        0,
        4,
        0
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you getting data as a array..? or you are getting data that is posted here only..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop should be like this..in your code you checked i with length of   data.. instead you must check it with `images` or `likes` or `comments` `length` (If your data object is not an array..)
See the edited code below

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.images.length; i++) {
                var image = data.images[i];
                var likes = data.likes[i];
                var comments = data.comments[i];
                var nextid=data.next_id;
                $(".row").append("<div class='col-md-2 col-sm-3'><div class='thumbnail'><img src='"+image+"' style='width: 100%;' alt='Gallery Image'><p><br/> Likes:"+likes+"  <br/> Comments: "+comments+" </p></div></div>");
    }
```

Comment: I just copy your for loop part and replace with my for loop

Comment: That is y i am asking you to share jsFiddle so I can remove errors

Answer (score 0):

Since `data` is not an array but an object, `data[i]` is probably not defined.
You should remove those brackets, I guess: `data[i].likes[i]` => `data.likes[i]`.